# Looping strings to create attributes in class constructor - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

I've been stuck on this for a while. I cannot access the value of  an object's attribute once constructed, but console prints the names just fine. The names and number of attributes needs to be dynamic and change depending on what source they come from. Therefore I can't just use a consistent way.

```
starting_list = ["Comapny", "Contact Name", "Email", "Phone", "URL", "Country", "Source"]

class NewClass(object):
    _myattrib = None

    def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
        super().__setattr__('myattrib', val)
        print("setting myattrib")

    def __init__(self):
        for item in starting_list:
            #cleaning up a bit
            item = str(item)
            item = item.lower()
            item = item.strip()
            item = item.replace(' ', '_')
            self.__setattr__(self, item, 'hi')
            print(item) #it reads it here

print(NewClass.url)
```

any help would be apprecieated.

Comment: Well, you've written your `__setattr__()` method to always set the attribute `myattrib` rather than using the actual attribute name, so I presume it's doing what you told it to.

Comment: Normally, `__setattr__()` isn't called directly. Also, the way you're calling it looks like it would raise an error. Try `setattr(self, name, value)`. Also, `str(item)` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I'm more interested in your reasoning behind needing dynamic attributes. I'd bet it's unnecessary.

Comment: i want to be able to use different csv inputs and preserve the data but add to it new data.  I'd have to edit the script to include the headers of each csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update the objects `__dict__` attribute instead of messing around with `__setattr__`

```
class NewClass:
  def __init__(self, items=(), default='hi'):
    sanitized = (str(item).lower().strip().replace(' ', '_') for item in items)
    self.__dict__.update({item: default for item in sanitized})

starting_list = ["Comapny", "Contact Name", "Email", "Phone", "URL", "Country", "Source"]

nc = NewClass(starting_list)

print(nc.email) # prints hi
```

Edit: split some lines up for readability

Comment: ahhhh. Thanks. I tried `dict.fromkeys()` but didnt think to update the `self.__dict__`. Thanks a million